# Java Switch Statement: creating a calculator error

Tags: java, calculator

I was wondering if anyone can see what is wrong with my code. It works except that the program is not acknowledging my switch statement - I searched lots of questions but as I am a novice I am clearly missing something.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Calmlr1 {
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String anotherOption = "y", operatorOpt= "a";
        int no1=0, no2=0;
        double result= 0;
        System.out.println ("Welcome to the online calculator! Let's begin...");
        while (anotherOption.equalsIgnoreCase ("y")) {
            System.out.println ("Please enter your 1st number: ");
            no1 = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println ("Please confirm your operator:\n1 = +\n2 = - \n3 = *\n4 = /");
            operatorOpt = input.next ();
            System.out.println ("Please enter your 2nd number: ");
            no2 = input.nextInt();

            switch(no1) {
              case 1:
                result=no1+no2;
                break;
              case 2:
                result=no1-no2;
                break;
              case 3:
                result=no1*no2;
                break;
              case 4:
                result=no1/no2; 
              default: 
                result = 0 ;
                break;
            }
            System.out.println("Your total calculation is: "+result);
            System.out.println("Would you like to do another sum? y/n ");
            anotherOption=input.next();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Its ok I figured it out yaaaaaayyyy!!!! :) needed to change the operatorOpt into a int not string and wala it works :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using `switch(operatorOpt)`. Right now you are switching on the first number.

You also need to change:

`int operatorOpt= 0;`

`operatorOpt = input.nextInt();`

That is, if you want to keep your switch statement the same. Please also see @Daniel Imms answer for an additional bug fix.

Comment: :) thank you, I realised that when looking in my book - such a relief when it works thank you for commenting :)

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a `break` at the end of `case 4`

```
case 4:
result=no1/no2; 
break;
```

**EDIT** J L's answer is the main issue, but this is another problem that will break division.

Comment: Whomever get the combination of the two answers first gets my vote. Edit - Hugo Sousa got it first.

Answer (score 1):

Your `switch` should be on the `operatorOpt` and not on `no1`.

Also, you're missing a `break` in the `case 4`. So, if you want to do a division, you'll get `0` as result.

The input from the user for `operatorOpt` should be done with `input.nextLine()`. Or, if you want to keep the same `switch` statement, with `input.nextInt()`.

It should be like this:

```
switch(operatorOpt)
{
    case "+":
    result=no1+no2;
    break;
    case "-":
    result=no1-no2;
    break;
    case "*":
    result=no1*no2;
    break;
    case "/":
    result=no1/no2; 
    break;
    default: 
    result = 0 ;
    break;
}
```

Comment: Assuming they're using Java 7+.

Answer (score 0):

Your switch statement should be on "operatorOpt" and not on "no1" as you suppose to check the operator and based on that you want to do the calculation. However, you must use JDK1.7 to use String in Switch statement since previous versions of JDK do not support String Switch.
Also, you should use "break" in case 4.

Answer (score 0):

Your switch should be on the operatorOpt and not on no1.

You can use like this

```
switch(operatorOpt)
{
    case "+":
        result=no1+no2;
        break;
    case "-":
        result=no1-no2;
        break;
    case "*":
        result=no1*no2;
        break;
    case "/":
        result=no1/no2; 
        break;
    default: 
        result = 0 ;
        break;
}
```

Comment: Your answer is almost identical to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21632774/334849) from 30 minutes ago... why post the same thing?

Comment: I searched and couldn't find anything similar, maybe the tags on the previous question need to be edited. Less of the negative comments we are all here to learn not moan at a "repeated question".